# Spring Data REST: How to specify a RepositoryRestResource as the app's entry point

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Currently, navigating to the app's root, e.g.

`http://localhost:8080/api`

returns links to all of the exported resources. However, I would like only one particular resource to be returned here (we'll call this resource `StartResource`). All of the other resources can be accessible by traversing links from the `StartResource`.

After reading Spring Data REST's [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/), it isn't clear to me how this can be accomplished. The section on [restricting](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#_which_repositories_get_exposed_by_defaults) which resources are exported seems related, but I am not clear on what `exporting` means in this case - are not-exported still given endpoints that are hidden, or are they not given endpoints at all?

As an aside, it may be better to impose this  restriction on the client side anyway, but I am still curious how this logic would be implemented.

Comment: Annotating a repository with `@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)` means there is no endpoint to interact with the resources handled by the repository. I understand that is not what you're looking for. Could you provide a sample of what StartRepository looks like, and what you'd like to get on the root page?

Answer (score 0):

To change or add links to the root endpoint you can use [ResourceProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#_the_resourceprocessor_interface) for [RepositoryLinksResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryLinksResource.html) there you can remove all links, add your own links or even create your custom 'rootResource' and return it instead of original one:

```
@Component
public class RootResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource> {

    @Override
    public RepositoryLinksResource process(RepositoryLinksResource resource) {

        // resource.removeLinks();
        // resource.add(new Link(...));
        // return resource;
        CustomRootResource rootResource = new CustomRootResource();        
        rootResource.add(new Link(...));
        return rootResource;
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomRootResource extends RepositoryLinksResource {
    private String test = "test";
}
```